# AppleScript extract before delimiter from result of shell script

Tags: applescript, command-line

I would like to extract name from text list.

Result from `do shell shell` command:

```
set Clist to do shell command "ls ./"
```

Is:

```
John_01044445558_pass.jpg<br>
Jane_01044562738_visa.jpg<br>
Doe_01027381938_pass.jpg<br>
Joe_7485.jpg
```

I need `John` `Jane` `Doe` `Joe` from that list in this format:

```
John, Jane, Doe, Joe
```

How can I achieve this?

Here is Full script.

```
tell application "Finder"
set fullname to name of (selection as alias)
set Cdate to do shell script "date '+%Y.%m.%d'"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}
if fullname contains ".jpg" then
    set CnameNFD to first text item of fullname
    set Cmobile to second text item of fullname
    set Ccustomer to second text item of fullname
    set Ctemp to "/Volumes/homes/macbook/Save/"
    set Clink to "https://r.loyverse.com/dashboard/#/clients/database?page=0&limit=10&search="
    set Cname to ¬
        do shell script "echo " & (CnameNFD as text) & "|iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8"
    --Save폴더에서 전화번호로 검색된리스트를 이름만 가져옴
    --      set Cppl to do shell script "Ctemp=" & Ctemp & " Cmobile=" & Cmobile & ";ls $Ctemp | grep $Cmobile | awk -F'_' '{print $1}' "
    set Cppl to do shell script "Ctemp=" & Ctemp & " Cmobile=" & Cmobile & ";ls $Ctemp | grep $Cmobile "
    set lsOutputAsList to ¬
        paragraphs of ¬
        Cppl
    set theNamesList to {}
    repeat with thisItem in lsOutputAsList
        copy first text item of thisItem ¬
            to the end of theNamesList
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
    set theNames to theNamesList as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    do shell script "Cname=" & Cname & " Cmobile=" & Cmobile & " Ccustomer=" & Ccustomer & " theNames=" & theNames & "; echo \"'$theNames'\""
```

else
display dialog "올바른 파일을 선택하십시오." buttons {"Okay"} default button 1
end if
end tell

If I display dialog theNames it shows as I expected.
But I run with shell script echo theNames it shows nothing.
I need to use theNames variable to curl post.

Comment: Just an FYI... The `$PWD` of a `do shell script` _command_ is `/` and as such there is no way that the _variable_ `Clist` in  `set Clist to do shell command "ls ./"` will contain the _output_ you've shown. It will contain a listing of what is in the _root_ of the,  e.g., **Macintosh HD**. In other words, `set Clist to paragraphs of (do shell command "ls ./")` will be: `{"Applications", "Library", "System", "Users", "Volumes", "bin", "cores", "dev", "etc", "home", "opt", "private", "sbin", "tmp", "usr", "var"}`

Comment: The reason why I am do shell command ls ./ is the path is already set to specific folder at the very beginning of the script. I will update full script when I get back home.

Comment: I guess its because of “, ”. 
If I change it to “,” it works. 
Then, I can’t use “space after comma” while using shell script?

Comment: You shouldn’t parse the output of `ls`. It says so in its own `man` page. Its output can vary considerably between systems, between shells, between versions of macOS, or simply between folders.  Instead of `do shell script "ls $Ctemp | grep $Cmobile"`, use `do shell script "cd \"$Ctemp\"; printf '%s\n' *\"$Cmobile\"*"`, or `the name of every file in the folder named (Ctemp as POSIX file) whose name contains Cmobile`.

Answer (score 1):

> I need John Jane Doe Joe from that list in this format. John, Jane, Doe, Joe
>
> How can I achieve this?

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes the output of your `do shell script` *command* is:

```
John_01044445558_pass.jpg
Jane_01044562738_visa.jpg
Doe_01027381938_pass.jpg
Joe_7485.jpg
```

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set lsOutputAsList to ¬
    paragraphs of ¬
    "John_01044445558_pass.jpg
Jane_01044562738_visa.jpg
Doe_01027381938_pass.jpg
Joe_7485.jpg"

set theNamesList to {}

set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "_"}

repeat with thisItem in lsOutputAsList
    copy first text item of thisItem ¬
        to the end of theNamesList
end repeat

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set theNames to theNamesList as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

return theNames
```

**Result:** `John, Jane, Doe, Joe`

---

### What the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is doing:

```
set lsOutputAsList to ¬
    paragraphs of ¬
```

Converts the *output* of the `ls` *command* run in a `do shell script` *command* to a *list* instead  of *carriage return* (**CR** or *hex* **0D**) terminated lines of *text*. This is done so as to be able to easily *loop* through and *manipulate* the *output* returned.

Note that this is an *example* and meant as a place holder for:

```
set Clist to paragraphs of (do shell command "ls ./")
```

Where the actual `do shell script` *command* returns the *output* shown in the OP, meaning the `do shell script` *command* as shown is not really the actual *shell command*. See my comment to the OP, which is repeated in the **Notes:** *section* at the end of this answer.

```
set theNamesList to {}
```

Creates a *list object* to store the *name* portion of the *filenames*.

```
set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
    {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "_"}
```

Uses `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to create a *list* of *text items* from the ensuing *filenames*, i.e., it coerces, e.g., `"John_01044445558_pass.jpg"`, the contents of `thisItem in lsOutputAsList` to `{"John", "01044445558_pass.jpg"}` in the `repeat` *loop*.

```
repeat with thisItem in lsOutputAsList
    copy first text item of thisItem ¬
        to the end of theNamesList
end repeat
```

For each *item* in the *list*, copy the first *text item*, e.g., `"John"`, in e.g., `{"John", "01044445558_pass.jpg"}` to the end of the `theNamesList` *list*.

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
```

Sets up a new `text item delimiter` to coerce the `theNamesList` *list* into a *string* of *text*.

```
set theNames to theNamesList as text
```

Coerces the `theNamesList` *list*, e.g., `{"John", "Jane", "Doe", "Joe"}` into a *string* of *text* to the *variable* `theNames`, e.g., `"John, Jane, Doe, Joe"`.

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
```

As a good practice, restores `AppleScript's text item delimiters` to the original `text item delimiter` which by default is `{""}`. While in some cases, ascertaining the current `text item delimiter` before modifying it, and restoring it after modifying it may not be programmatically necessary in a specific use case, nonetheless, I refer back to "As a good practice,".

```
return theNames
```

For demonstration purposes, returns the *value* of `theNames` *variable*, which in this *example* is: `John, Jane, Doe, Joe`

---

**Notes:**

Just an FYI... The `$PWD` of a `do shell script` *command* is `/` and as such there is no way that the *variable* `Clist` in  `set Clist to do shell command "ls ./"` will contain the *output* shown in the OP. It will contain a listing of what is in the *root* of the,  e.g., **Macintosh HD**. In other words, `set Clist to paragraphs of (do shell command "ls ./")` will be: `{"Applications", "Library", "System", "Users", "Volumes", "bin", "cores", "dev", "etc", "home", "opt", "private", "sbin", "tmp", "usr", "var"}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another **AppleScript** approach which will return the names as you need them.

```
-- Choose The Folder That Contains  Files With The Underscores In
-- Which The Names Need To Be Extracted

activate
set sourceFolder to quoted form of (POSIX path of (choose folder))

set text item delimiters to ", "
set namesList to paragraphs of (do shell script "find " & sourceFolder & ¬
    " -name '*_*.jpg' -exec basename {} \\; | sed 's/_.*//'") as text
set text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: @user3439894 I can always count on you to scrutinize my code.  Good looking out ; )

Comment: I edited your _code_ as `-name '*.jpg' -and -name '*_*'` was not really necessary since using a single `-name` _primary_, e.g. `-name '*_*.jpg'` does the job. I edited the `sed` _command_ as the use the `-E` _option_ was only necessitated by your use of `+` instead of the default `*`. Searching for an `_` _character_ doesn't require treating a **BRE** as an **ERE**. Also changed the _pattern delimiters_ to the default `/` as there was no real (programatic) need to use an alternate _delimiter_. Users not familiar with `sed` may be confused by `@` as the `sed` _manual page_ uses `/`.